# Why doesn't energy supply rate equal the dissipation rate for electrical energy transmissions?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

I was recently reading an example which showed that the average rate of energy dissipation due to resistance of the wires that are used in the transmission of electricity from a generator is not equal to the average rate at which the energy is supplied. But this would imply that current doesn't depend on the resistance of the wires. How can this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy that is supplied by the generator goes to energy dissipated by the transmission wires but also (usually mostly) by the load at the other end of the transmission lines.  Does that explain why it's not all consumed by the transmission lines?

Answer (score 0):

The current in the wires is partially dependent on the resistance. Typically a transmission line has a transformer at the generator and one at the consumer end. The consume applies a load $R_{L}$ to the secondary of the transformer. On the transmission line side of the transformer, $R_{L}$ appears as a larger resistance  $R'_{L}$ in series with the resistance of the wire  $R_{w}$. The generator applies a voltage $V_{G}$ to the transformer at that end which steps the voltage up to the transmission line side $V'_{G}$. $V'_{G}$, $R_{w}$,$R'_{L}$ form a series circuit.

So by Ohm's Law: $I_{line} = V'_{G}/(R_{w}+R'_{L})$.

Even though $R_{w}$ is small in comparison to $R'_{L}$, It is large enough to influence the current flow to cause the metal in the transmission line to heat up. The primary cause of the current flow is the load supplied by the consumer.